# pyspark: How to submit depend files & folders?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to submit a `pyspark task`. And some `.py` files in different folders.Especially I want put configuration files and common tools in only one folder. But when I submit a pyspark task, I just know `--py-files` param, so how to submit folders? My code struct likes:

```
--conf folder
|  --origin.conf
|  --scenes.conf
--tools folder
|  --utils.py
|  --vali.py
-- other fodlsers...
```

Comment: what did you try to do? what failed?

Comment: you have to create a zip with all your stuff

Comment: @Yaron For example, a file --plot_distribution.py-- in folder data_analysis ,has a statement --from tools import utils--,which tools is also a folder. And other py files also depend on utils.py,so I want to submit folders not only files.

Comment: @BlackBear Hi, an example or documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- create [Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to organize the code
- zip package or create [egg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg)
- submit your app passing egg or zip file to `--py-files` / `sc.pyFiles`

Answer (score 0):

This link from Cloudera has some examples of distributing python packages to Spark executors
[Running Spark Python Applications](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_python.html)