# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.0 in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am deploying a django project using heroku cloud platform. I have added the dependencies in requirements.txt file. However when I push to heroku master, I get the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_bc8be989466414998410d3ef4c97a115/requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_bc8be989466414998410d3ef4c97a115/requirements.txt (line 17)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_bc8be989466414998410d3ef4c97a115/requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to what-the-image.
remote:
```

I am using Django v 1.10 and python 2.7. Where would I be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to install Tensorflow on Heroku by using a [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/).

Simply replace the `tensorflow==1.0.0` line in your requirements.txt with `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

[Wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) and [eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg) are packaging formats for Python code. Wheels are intended to replace the older egg format and generally much more versatile as they don't require a compiler to be available (very useful when deploying to PaaS like Heroku, Microsoft's Azure).

One thing to note about wheels is the [naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/), which reflects the architecture and Python version they are meant to be used on. A quick way to find the type of wheel your system supports is via:

```
import pip
print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

Comment: Dafuq ? Could you explain what's going on with this please ? Also, thanks, it worked :-)

Comment: Added info to the answer. Gotta love a language in which you can compare wheels with eggs :)