# ignore *.egg-info directories with ack-grep

Tags: python, ack

I've noticed that ack-grep doesn't ignore the `<module>.egg-info` directory that python creates alongside the source code. I was hoping I could add

```
--ignore-dir=*.egg-info
or
--ignore-file=ext:egg-info
```

as a catchall without having to add each project's .egg-info directory manually to ~/.ackrc.

Is there a way to do this without having to manually add all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same filtering system to specify `--ignore-dir` as you can when specifying types.  Use `ack --dump` to see the default settings, and they should give you an idea of how to do this.  (As well as seeing the "Specifying your own types" in the manual at `ack --man`)

So you can do this:

```
ack --ignore-dir=match:[.]egginfo$ whatever
```

Note that when you're using `match`, it's a Perl regular expression, not a glob.  What this is saying is "Ignore any directory that matches `.egginfo` at the end of the name".  The `.` is a metacharacter that is put in a character class (`[.]`) to remove its special meaning.  You could also have used `\.`, but then that runs into confusion with the shell, too.

So you can drop that `--ignore-dir=match:[.]egginfo$` in your ~/.ackrc and not worry about it any more.

...

For those of us who aren't familiar with the Python ecosystem, can you say more about what the `<module>.egg-info` directories are, and where and how they get created?  Is it basically a build directory?  I'm the author of ack, and it sounds like something that might be good for ack to ignore by default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg has great overviews