# Portable Python Installation

Tags: python, pip, installation, portability

I'm trying to figure out the best way to install Python for my setup.
I travel between school and home every day and I use a 2TB Portable Drive for my files.
The computers at school are locked so that you cannot install there, but I bet I can install things on my drive and use them fine, as well as use portable applications just fine.

I was looking into ways of getting Python on both my drive and my computer so that my Python on my main computer will always work and my drive's Python is available when I want to work with it.

Of course, the problem is that Python won't install like that. It bricks either installation first, and I saw a post on *virtualenv*, but it seems like it's more of a project by project based solution for isolating *imports/modules* of sorts.

I'm not too good with this stuff and installing tons of programs and waiting for them to uninstall only to not figure it out isn't my thing, so maybe someone on here knows what I'm talking about? Thanks.

By the way, yes, I want both installations to have the same pip stuff, the portable one I currently use at school is having a rough time installing things like *json, requests* and other fun stuff that is essential to my scripts.

Comment: Is on school computer installed putty or ssh client of some sorts?

Comment: What OS do you use? On windows, you can use the embedded python (download the zip and unpack, available since Python 3.5); on linux, you can easily compile one yourself and install it onto your removable disk. If using the same path to mount the disk on both computers, it should work just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make python portable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488174/how-to-make-python-portable)

Answer (score 0):

I presume your OS is windows.

Try to use `cygwin` (a `linux` emulator) that will allow you to install whatever utility you need on the `cygwin installation` directory (in your case would be your thumb drive). Launching than `cygwin` from your drive, you have a working environment for pretty much all the things you can imagine. If you `export DISPLAY` to your windows, than you can have `GUI` utilities, too.