# Portable python script in Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I made a portable python script on Windows, by putting the whole python folder into the root directory:

```
ProjectFolder
|- run.bat
|- main.py
|- python <--- Python 3.10.1, downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3101/
 |- ...
 |- python.exe
 |- ...
```

`run.bat`

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
start "%cd%\python\python.exe" main.py
```

It works well on my side, but not on some of the others' systems.

Note: **all** testers do not have python installed in their OS, but only **some** of them have this error:

Windows will ask for an application to open `.py` file, or simply open a notepad -- I think I should have specified `python.exe` which could run the `.py` file.

May I know what exactly caused this problem?

Comment: Do they all have the same version of **Python** as yours?

Comment: @FerasAlfrih All testers do not have python pre-installed. I put python 3.10 in the project folder. So I think they are supposed to use that same version of Python...

Comment: If you had read the Command Prompt output of the usage information for the `start` command, you'd have noticed that the first double-quoted string is parsed as the window title. So when you use `start "%cd%\python\python.exe" main.py` your code is running `start main.py`, with the Window Title `%cd%\python\python.exe`. This means that their system looks for whatever application is configured to run `.py` files. If they already have a python.exe version registered, it will use that, if they don't it will trigger the prompt. What you need therefore is `start "" "%cd%\python\python.exe" main.py`.

Comment: Please add a few details: How do you run the batch file? What do the variable replacements in that file evaluate to?

Comment: Either duplicate, either should have better specified name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488174/how-to-make-python-portable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my earlier comment, if you had read the Command Prompt output of the usage information for the `start` command, you'd have noticed that the first double-quoted string is parsed as the window title; i.e.

```
C:\users\TaihouKai>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
      [command/program] [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
    path        Starting directory.
…
```

So when you use `start "%cd%\python\python.exe" main.py` your code is running `start main.py`, with the Window Title `%cd%\python\python.exe`.

This means that their system looks for whatever application is configured to run `.py` files. If they already have an executable file, *(most likely `python.exe`)* registered, it will use that, if they don't it will trigger the 'Choose an application…' prompt.

What you need therefore is a title, even an empty one, to prevent that parsing issue of the first double-quoted string.

```sh
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@CD /D "%~dp0"
@Start "" "%CD%\python\python.exe" main.py
```

Although, in your case, as you have a known directory structure, and it does not include any characters which require double-quoting, I'd say that you could probably do it like this:

```sh
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@CD /D "%~dp0"
@Start python\python.exe main.py
```

Alternatively you could use the `/D` option for `start` to predefine the working directory:

```sh
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@Start "" /D "%~dp0." "%~dp0python\python.exe" "main.py"
```

*This final example encloses all strings with double-quotes as a robust, rule of thumb, safety habit.*