# How to have egg files from github install with pip not in current directory but in the conda env directory?

Tags: python, git, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I am creating a python env using conda, pip and yml config file by using first:

```
conda env create -f test.yml -n test_pip
```

then

```
conda env update -f test.yml -n test_pip
```

with the following .yml file (for test only):

```
channels:
- defaults
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.5
- numpy
- scipy
- scikit-learn
- jupyter
- ipykernel
- requests
- pandas
- seaborn
- click
- openpyxl
- matplotlib
- pip:
  - watermark
  - "-e git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap#egg=shap"
  - pytest
  - sklearn
  - autopep8
```

It works fine but the egg file is install in the current dir "src/shap/" while I would like to have it install with all other python packages installed by conda or pip:

```
/xxx/anaconda/envs/test_pip
```

I took this test github directory (I know I can install it with pip install directly) but I would like to use later my own git directory.

Why is the egg not installed here?

```
/xxx/anaconda/envs/test_pip/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

It is the place where I fin the other packages installed by pip and conda.

Any reason for that ? How can I changed that ?

I am using:

```
anaconda 4.2.0
conda 4.5.1
pip 9.0.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any egg **file** in your config. If by the "egg file" you
mean git repository from github than the culprit is option `-e` — it
installs the package in ["editable mode"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs). You probably don't need it, so
the part of the config should look like this:

```
- pip:
    …
  - "git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap#egg=shap"
    …
```

PS. `#egg=shap` doesn't mean there is an egg file, it's just the way to
name the package for `pip` in VCS (git in your case) URLs so `pip` could resolve package names and versions before it clones the repositories.

Comment: I got confused by the "#egg=" but you are right I just want to install a git repository. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg. It works like a charm for this shap got repository and should work as well for my own git repository. I don't know why I was using "-e" and this was creating the issue.