# Pip install local package in conda environemnt

Tags: installation, pip, package, conda, local

I recently developed a package `my_package` and am hosting it on GitHub. For easy installation and use, I have following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_package',
      version='1.0',
      description='My super cool package',
      url='https://github.com/my_name/my_package',
      packages=['my_package'],
      python_requieres='3.9',
      install_requires=[
            'some_package==1.0.0'
      ])
```

Now I am trying to install this package in a conda environment:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.9
conda activate myenv 
pip install git+'https://github.com/my_name/my_package'
```

So far so good. If I try to use it in the project folder, everything works perfectly. If I try to use the packet outside the project folder (still inside the conda environment), I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'

I am working on windows, if that matters.

EDIT:

I'm verifying that both python and pip are pointing towards the correct version with:

```
which pip 
which python

/c/Anaconda3/envs/my_env/python
/c/Anaconda3/envs/my_env/Scripts/pip
```

Also, when I run:

```
pip show my_package
```

I get a description of my package. So pip finds it, but as soon as I try to `import my_package` in the script, I get the described error.

I also verified that the package is installed in my environment. So in `/c/Anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/site-packages` there is a folder `my_package-1.0.dist-info/`

Further: python "import sys, print(sys.path)"

shows, among other paths, `/c/Anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/site-packages`. So it is in the path.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995662/how-to-have-egg-files-from-github-install-with-pip-not-in-current-directory-but

Comment: Dit not help solving the issue

Comment: Okay. Could you please add some more details about the situation? Where is the package getting installed if not in the environment's `${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.9/site-packages`? How are you verifying that the environment is properly activated and that the `pip` corresponds to the environment?

Comment: To create and activate the environment I run the commands described in my post. If I then run ´conda list´ with this environment activated, I can see my_package listed. Also both ´which python´ and ´which pip´ correspond to the environment environmentfolder.

Comment: I updated my original post with some additional information

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using some explicit [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your script pointing to other Python interpreters.

Eg. using the system default Python:

```
#!/bin/env python
...
```

Answer (score 1):

While inside your environment `myenv`, try to uninstall your package first, to do a clean test:

```
pip uninstall my_package
```

Also, you have a typo in your `setup.py`: python_requieres --> python_requires.

And I actually tried to install with your setup.py, and also got `ModuleNotFoundError` - but because it didn't properly install due to `install_requires`:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement some_package==1.0.0
```

So, check also that everything installs without errors and warnings.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would like to point out (not the solution) regards the following statement you made:

> If I try to use it in the project folder [...] If I try to use the packet outside the project folder [...]

I understand "project folder" means the "`my_package`" folder (inside the git repository). *If that is the case*, I would like to point out that you are mixing two situations: that of *testing a (remote) package installation*, while *in your (local) repository*. Which is not necessarily wrong, but error-prone.

> Whenever testing the setup/install process of a package, make sure to move far from your repository (say, "/tmp/" equivalent in Windows) and, preferably, use a fresh environment. That will eliminate "noise" in your tests.

1. First thing I would tell you to do -- if not already -- is to create a fresh conda env and install your package from an empty/new folder. Eg,

   ```bash
   $ conda env create -n test_my_package ipython pip
   $ cd /tmp    # equivalent temporary or new in your Windows
   $ pip install git+https://github.com/my_name/my_package
   ```
2. If that doesn't work (maybe a problem with your pip' git+http code), do another way: [create a release for your package](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository#creating-a-release) (eg, "`v1`") and then install *the released* version by indicating the zip package URL (that you get from your "my_package" releases page on Github):

   ```bash
   $ pip install https://github.com/my_name/my_package/archive/v1.zip
   ```