# Mac OS: python from command line tools used instead of PATH

Tags: python-3.x, git, macos, developer-tools

When I run a "git commit" command I get the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named pre_commit
```

pre_commit is actually installed, and my PATH looks like this:

```
/Users/xxx/.jenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/xxx/.fig/bin:/Users/xxx/.local/bin:/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
```

Why does git assume it needs to use the command line tools (XCode) version of Python, even though it is not set anywhere in the path?
Pre-commit is correctly installed in the brew-installed version of Python.

```
➜ which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

Thank you
Thomas

Comment: If the pre-commit hook is implemented in Python, there should be a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the first line in `pre-commit`. The shebang in your pre-commit might be different.  If there is such shebang, you could run `/usr/bin/env python` and then run `import sys;sys.executable` to find what the current python is.

Answer (score 2):

`$PATH` determines the search behavior of the *shell*, when the shell is asked to run a command that does not have an absolute path name.  That is:

```
python
```

means "find some command named `python` that can be run".  A shell that uses `$PATH` (bash, sh, zsh, and many others) will iterate through each colon-separated component element *in* `$PATH` and try them in the order they appear.

(Side note: csh and tcsh use `$path`, lowercase, which is an array built at shell start-up time from `$PATH`.  You can set `$PATH` before running them, or you can, e.g., `set path = ($path /usr/local/bin)` to add another path to the end of the `$path` array; setting `$path` exports a new `$PATH` setting.  Not many people still use tcsh as it's quite klunky and modern bash or zsh does everything tcsh does, but in the old days when computers were mostly measured in "kilo" or "mega" instead of "giga" units, tcsh was a lot smaller and faster.)

In order to *run* something, though, the "something"—whatever it is—must *actually be executable*.  That is, the `exec*` family of system calls and functions (`execve` being the most basic one) will ask the OS to replace the current process with a new one constructed by running some command.  The system call taks a path name (`/usr/local/bin/python` for instance) and tries to open that file "for execution".  The file must have the executable bit set (`chmod +x`) *and* have a valid "magic number" for the OS.

On macOS (and Linux and BSDs and Unix-derived systems in general), one special valid magic number is the one formed by the characters `#!`.  If the file begins with this string, the OS will read in the first block or so of the file—the details here are extremely OS-specific as they usually depend on the underlying virtual-memory and/or block-I/O system—and extract the first *line*, perhaps up to some maximum length (in the old days about 32 or 64 bytes, these days likely much longer).  This line should be terminated by a newline only (CRLF here messes things up on a lot of systems).  The line should consist of the `#!`, an optional blank, the path name of an *interpreter*, and then an optional blank and optional argument to pass to the program.

The exact details of handling here depend on the OS: some allow more than one argument, separated by spaces, some only one.  Some allow multiple blanks after `#!`, some only one.  In any case, the `#!` line—called a *shebang* line, as [ElpieKay commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72935844/mac-os-python-from-command-line-tools-used-instead-of-path#comment128823424_72935844) and as noted [in this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))—determines which *interpreter* is to be used.  The OS shifts the `argv` arguments up as needed to place the shebang line argument(s) in front of the remaining `argv` arguments passed to `execve`, so that if the script starts with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

then `execve("/path/to/script", argv, environ);` acts almost as if the program in question had invoked, instead:

```
argv = insert_at(1, "python", argv);
```

(in C using a hypothetical `insert_at`, or `argv.insert(1, "python")` in Python) followed by:

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", argv, environ);
```

So if a Python script begins with `#! /usr/bin/env python`, *and* is made executable, it will be *run by* the `/usr/bin/env` "interpreter" with argument `python`.

What `/usr/bin/env` does in this case is replicate the shell's search with `$PATH` (!).  So this is a sort of poor-man's version of:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec python $@
```

except that it takes no extra *line* in the file, which means that the entire file can be a Python script.  This avoids the need to use [polyglot programming techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)).

The whole point of all of this is to avoid hardcoding the *path* to the Python interpreter.  If we know that `python` is actually `/usr/local/bin/python3` we can just write:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3
```

and invoke the correct interpreter.  But on some systems, `python` is python2, or `python` is in `/usr/bin`, or `python` is somewhere in `/opt` (as yours is), or whatever.  We can't really solve the whole python2-vs-python3 problem here, but we can easily handle the path-searching issue by indirecting through `/usr/bin/env`, which is always in `/usr/bin`.

> Why does git assume it needs to use the command line tools (XCode) version of Python, even though it is not set anywhere in the path?

*Git* makes no such assumption: `git commit` tries to `execve` the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file.  (Git does not need to do `$PATH` searching here as it knows precisely where this file lives within the repository proper, in the hooks directory.  In other places, Git will do the `$PATH` searching, the same way the shell does, sometimes by using the shell, and sometimes using a library routine that does the same thing.)

That file should be executable and start with `#!`.  Look at it and see what it contains: it might be a *shell script*, or it might be a script in some other language.  If it *is* a shell script, it might contain a lot of code, perhaps including code that sets and exports its `PATH` variable.  That might cause it to find the XCode version of Python if and when it tries to invoke `python` without a path.

Now, as to:

> ```
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3:
> No module named pre_commit
> ```

Remember that *Python* reads `$PYTHONPATH` from the environment to set up Python's `sys.path`.  Import directives then look in `sys.path`, using a rather fancy mechanism so that Python can import "eggs" and "wheels" as well as actual files (see [What is a Python egg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051192/1256452) and its answers and links, and note that PEP-427 discourages directly importing wheels).

For these reasons, a lot of Python things use a bit of shell scripting first.  For instance, Python "virtual environments" work by manipulating both `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` before invoking a specific Python version.