# How can I install a PyPi equivalent from scratch?

Tags: python, pypi

I need to build an internal python package index server, starting from scratch. In house right now we use Python 2.6 and 2.7, and prefer installing packages using pip.

We don't *require* authentication, but it would help.

What's the easiest way to get a PyPi equivalent running internally?

I am aware of the existence of mypypi, djangopypi, Plone Software Center, and EggBasket, but I have not been able to find a simple clear set of steps to set one of these up in a modern environment; the most recent complete docs I found for any of them seemed to be Tarek Ziade's 2008 blog article on them but it's not clear how up to date that is (and that seems to pull in a huge dependency tree, to boot).

tldr; what's the *best* PyPi implementation, and how do I install it + configure it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235331/how-to-roll-my-own-pypi

Comment: note: if you just need to install packages with `pip --extra-index-url` then a simple directory listing that can be served by any webserver is enough e.g., `pinax` uses http://dist.pinaxproject.com/dev/

Answer (score 5):

Best is a relative term but I myself created ClueReleaseManager to deal with this need locally - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ClueReleaseManager