# Install package dependencies on CI-server virtual env

Tags: python, deployment, pip, software-distribution

For my application environment I use `virtualenv`. I have a script which installs the `virtualenv` and installs all needed packages based on `requirements.txt`.

This works perfectly for our distribution in our corporate network. I use a network share where all needed packages are placed. Each production system has access to it an can install it from there. My local dev-environment uses a local folder where all the packages located.

Now the problem: I want to setup a build server for **continuous integration**. Unfortunately, this server does **not** have access to the network-share but it has access to the packages via `git`.

What's the best way to also let the build-server install its dependencies from  `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your build server can access the packages via git and you want to install using `requirements.txt`, you're in luck.

### Installing Python Packages with git via requirements.txt

You can specify git based packages in `requirements.txt`. Just put them on separate lines as if they were another package:

`git+git://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache.git`

You can even pin to a specific commit using `@`:

`git+git://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache.git@40cfd9280dc66ea54df0961420fc94853d506a35`

#### Bonus Mode

If you want to pull from a repository in [editable mode](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#options), prepend a `-e`:

`-e git+git://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache.git@40cfd9280dc66ea54df0961420fc94853d506a35#egg=Flask-Cache`

### Roll your own PyPI Server

Though you didn't ask for it specifically, you could also [roll your own Python Package Index](http://aboutsimon.com/2012/02/24/create-a-local-pypi-mirror/).

Once you have it configured, you simply have to set the `index-url` to fetch packages from. You can do this directly:

```
pip install --index-url=http://pip.razer.domain/ -r requirements.txt
```

Or set up a config file `~/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
index-url = http://pip.razer.domain/
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How does  work with special versions? Eg I specify a package with version 1.1 how can pip pull that version when also other ones exist?

Comment: If it can only access via git, I don't think you have access to version (well, other than hitting up specific commits and branches).

Comment: Might I suggest [rolling your own PyPI server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556147/pypi-is-slow-how-do-i-run-my-own-server) that it can pull from?

Comment: It ended up to install `localshop` on my build server which is a local `PyPi` server

Comment: Oh hey, haven't used that yet. Thanks for pointing `localshop` out!