# Local mirror of Pypi that can download package on demand as Nexus

Tags: python, repository, nexus, mirror

I'm finding some application to provide me a local mirror of [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/simple/) on internet repository. But I'm not interested to download the entire Pypi repository, I need build my local repo on demand like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) external repositories.

For example:
my local.repo have package **A, B** then when I request package **C**, the package **C** and their dependencies are downloaded from an external repo (some pypi internet repo) and are stored on local.repo.

Anybody know some alternatives to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) which allows you to have indexes that inherit for each other, specifically you can create one index that you can push to locally that inherits from the root/pypi (which is a caching proxy), this allows you to push your artifacts and have them visible at the same address, if the name of your artifact collides with name in the proxy then yours will override.

Apparently, Artifactory can support something similar nowadays which could be useful if you have M2/Ivy repository requirements.

See also: [PyPI is slow. How do I run my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556147/pypi-is-slow-how-do-i-run-my-own-server)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use directly Nexus as PyPi repo provider in both host/proxy mode. It has been requested here:
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6037

And docs are available here:
https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/pypi.html

NOTE: Not all Nexus 2 functionalities are available in Nexus 3, some of them are slowly migrated, some of them will never be migrated, so we end-up running temporarily both version in parallel each for different purpose, but in case of pure PyPi integration, Nexus 3 is production ready.