# Distributing my python module inside organization

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I made some modules in python, and I want to distributed them inside my organization. These modules are already stored in BitBucket.

Is there any way to distribute them using "pip install" for example?

What is the correct way?

Comment: You may want to consider running an internal PyPI server: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235331/1394393.

Answer (score 4):

You can pip install from GitHub and you should be able to do so (not verified) from Bitbucket since it uses git as well.

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_username/my_repo.git@tagnumber
```

For private repos see:

[Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository)

You could just add the ssh keys in the right places to make it work.

Another option would be to run your own git remote instance on a server within your organization which might prevent the hassle of authentication for your colleagues.