# Best practice to install package dependency not available in pypi

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, requirements.txt

My python package depends on a private package that is not in pypi. You can assume that the structure of the private package is [this](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject).

**Goal**: store the 3rd party private package somewhere within my own package in a whatever way such that when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` (or even better `pip install <my_pkg_name>`), the 3rd party dependency is installed. This must work in Windows and Linux.

**A potential workaround**: Do not install the 3rd party module. Instead, place it in your main package directory as it is and `import` its modules.

```
/my_pkg
    /non_pypi_pkg
    /my_pkg
        module.py
```

Where `module.py` is able to `import non_pypi_pkg` without installing `non_pypi_pkg`.

**Question**: What what is the recommended practice to achieve the goal? Can we do any better than my workaround?

Comment: not sure of the context, but it's possible to set up your own local pypi mirror, and serve your own content there. maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235331/how-to-roll-my-own-pypi

Comment: Good point. I've already maintained a local pypi mirror in the past, but I'd like to use a simpler solution in this case.

Comment: No matter what option you choose, you need to write a `setup.py` for the private package. Then, setting up a private PyPI repo is one option, another would be installing from URL via `dependency_links` or even installing directly from VCS, again via `dependency_links`. `pip` can also handle VCS URLs, i.e. `pip install git+https://github.com/user/project@branch`.

Answer (score 2):

When I work with **third-party packages**, I often use one of the next methods using `setuptools`.

#### 1. Install directly indicating a URL path in `setup.py`.

*Having the following structure:*

```sh
/my_pkg
├── /my_pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
├── setup.py
```

*setup.py*

```py
setup(
    name="my_pkg",
    version="0.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['flask', 
        'non_pypi_pkg @ https://github.com/<user>/non_pypi_pkg/archive/main.zip#egg=non_pypi_pkg-0.0.1',
        ]
)
```

> When the repository is private I use a **personal access token** ([by github](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)), in the same example could be `pkg @ https://<token>@github.com/<user>/pkg/...`

- Then `pip install -e my_pkg`

#### 2. Working from a monorepo with multiple packages to enforce python separation layers.

*Having the following structure:*

```sh
/
├── my_pkg
│   ├── my_pkg
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module.py
│   └── setup.py
├── non_pypi_pkg
│   ├── non_pypi_pkg
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module_b.py
│   └── setup.py
```

*/non_pypi_pkg/setup.py*

```py
setup(
    name="non_pypi_pkg",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[]
)
```

*/my_pkg/setup.py*

```py
setup(
    name="my_pkg",
    version="0.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['flask', 'non_pypi_pkg']
)
```

- Here it is necessary to install in order of dependence. For example:

  ```
   pip install -e non_pypi_pkg; pip install -e my_pkg;
  ```

> I prefer to use a script as a `Makefile` for these tasks but is possible too with a `bash` or `power-shell` script like as next:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
libraries=(non_pypi_pkg my_pkg)

for dirname in $(ls); do
    if [ -d "$dirname" ] && [ -e "$dirname/setup.py" ]; then
        pip install -e $dirname
    fi
done
```